# Errors in the CV template by Scott Clark

Tags: errors, templates, cv

I downloaded a CV Template. It got succesfully compiled in ShareLaTeX and WriteLaTeX. But In my TeXLive Distribution, I am getting errors.

Here is the code:

```
% (c) 2002 Matthew Boedicker <mboedick@mboedick.org> (original author) http://mboedick.org
% (c) 2003-2007 David J. Grant <davidgrant-at-gmail.com> http://www.davidgrant.ca
% (c) 2008 Nathaniel Johnston <nathaniel@nathanieljohnston.com> http://www.nathanieljohnston.com
%
% (c) 2012 Scott Clark <sc932@cornell.edu> cam.cornell.edu/~sc932
%
%This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 2.5 License. To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/2.5/ or send a letter to Creative Commons, 543 Howard Street, 5th Floor, San Francisco, California, 94105, USA.

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tocloft}


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Edit these values as you see fit

\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  % Width of border outside of title bars
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  % Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  % Inner background color of title bars


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Margin setup

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\vspace{8pt}
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}
    \begin{shaded}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
    \end{shaded}
  }\vspace{-5pt}
}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{\Large Your Name} & \textbf{\today} \\
Short description of you & E-mail \\
Adress & Homepage \\
\end{tabular*}
\\


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Education}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{itemize}

\item \ressubheading{University Name}{City, Country}{BSc, MSc, PhD, or something else}{2009 - 2013}

\begin{itemize}
    \resitem{Additional description nr 1}
    \resitem{Additional description nr 2}
\end{itemize}

\item \ressubheading{Other University Name}{City, Country}{BSc, MSc, PhD, or something else}{2004 - 2009}

\end{itemize}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Some important section}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{enumerate}
 \item First item
 \item Second item
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
 \item First item
 \item Second item
\end{itemize}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Awards, Grants \& Honours}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \vspace{-2pt}
    \begin{center}\begin{tabular*}{6.6in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Nobel Prize \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep} 2013}\\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Big grant \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep} 2010-2013}\\
        \vphantom{E}
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}\vspace*{-16pt}


\end{document}
```

The errors I get are :

```
--TeX said--
\cftdotfill #1->\def \@tempa
{#1}\def \@tempb {\cftnodots} \ifx \@tempa .... l.77

--TeX said--
<inserted text>
\inaccesible
l77
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem seems too localized and can  not be reproduced in another standard LaTeX distribution.

Comment: @MMA: I get the same error.

Comment: @subhamsoni Please insert the errors as text so that others with the same problem can find this question through searching.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are better ways to obtain fixed-width `tabular`s - the main problem with the current template. I've swapped out the use of `tabular*` with `tabularx`, provided by the [`tabularx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) (and some [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) pizzaz):

[image]

```
% (c) 2002 Matthew Boedicker <mboedick@mboedick.org> (original author) http://mboedick.org
% (c) 2003-2007 David J. Grant <davidgrant-at-gmail.com> http://www.davidgrant.ca
% (c) 2008 Nathaniel Johnston <nathaniel@nathanieljohnston.com> http://www.nathanieljohnston.com
%
% (c) 2012 Scott Clark <sc932@cornell.edu> cam.cornell.edu/~sc932
%
%This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 2.5 License. To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/2.5/ or send a letter to Creative Commons, 543 Howard Street, 5th Floor, San Francisco, California, 94105, USA.

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed,tabularx,array}
\usepackage{tocloft}


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Edit these values as you see fit

\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  % Width of border outside of title bars
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  % Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  % Inner background color of title bars


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Margin setup

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\vspace{8pt}
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}
    \begin{shaded}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
    \end{shaded}
  }\vspace{-5pt}
}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabularx}{6.5in}{X<{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}@{}r}
  \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
  \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabularx}\vspace{-6pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{7in}{Xr}
  \textbf{\Large Your Name} & \textbf{\today} \\
  Short description of you & E-mail \\
  Adress & Homepage \\
\end{tabularx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Education}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{itemize}

\item \ressubheading{University Name}{City, Country}{BSc, MSc, PhD, or something else}{2009 - 2013}

\begin{itemize}
  \resitem{Additional description nr 1}
  \resitem{Additional description nr 2}
\end{itemize}

\item \ressubheading{Other University Name}{City, Country}{BSc, MSc, PhD, or something else}{2004 - 2009}

\end{itemize}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Some important section}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
\end{itemize}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Awards, Grants \& Honours}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vspace{-2pt}
\begin{center}\begin{tabular*}{6.6in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Nobel Prize \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep} 2013}\\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Big grant \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep} 2010-2013}\\
  \vphantom{E}
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}\vspace*{-16pt}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

I get the error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\cftdotfill #1->\def \@tempa 
                             {#1}\def \@tempb {\cftnodots }\ifx \@tempa \@te...
...
```

`\cftdotfill` is part of a table column specification in macro `\ressubheading`:

```
\begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
```

There it gets expanded via `\edef` and breaks because of the assignment that is not executed in an expansion context.

This issue can be fixed by making `\cftdotfill` robust:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\cftdotfill
```