# Create a tex section in cv template keeping the layout of a custom command

Tags: sectioning, cv

I am using this template for my CV by Scott Clark. As explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172569/60344) I substituted `tabular*` with `tabularx` to make it compile.

In the template he has defined the command `resheading` to identify different sections. The command is the following:

```
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\vspace{8pt}
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}
    \begin{shaded}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
    \end{shaded}
  }\vspace{-5pt}
}
```

and creates this layout:

[image]

However in the tex editor this command does not create a real section that can be identified easily and the file becomes difficult to manage and edit after a while. I would like to keep the same layout but add a section, something like `\section{\resheading{}}`; however, this does not work. Is there a simple way to keep the same layout and create a tex section ?

I tried to use the package `titlesec`. Starting from this:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{ugentblauw}}{\thesection}{1em}{#1}}
```

I copied the commands of `resheading`

```
\titleformat{\section}{\vspace{8pt}
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}
    \begin{shaded}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
    \end{shaded}
  }\vspace{-5pt}}{\thesection}{1em}{#1}}
```

but I got the error `Illegal parameter number`.

I tried also:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\vspace{8pt}\arabic{section}
 \begin{shaded}
 \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
    \end{shaded}
 }
```

but got the same error.

**MINIMAL COMPLETE WORKING EXAMPLE**

The following is the code with only the definition of the custom command I am currently using, the needed packages and other stuff to compile the tex file.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  % Width of border outside of title bars
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  % Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  % Inner background color of title bars

%--------------------------Margin setup---------------------------------
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\vspace{8pt}
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}
    \begin{shaded}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
    \end{shaded}
  }\vspace{-5pt}
}
%-----------------------------------------------------------    
\begin{document}    
    \resheading{Education}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `titlesec` package can be used to define custom layouts for sectioning commands, including `\section`.

Comment: Exactly how? I tried to move the part after `\newcommand{\resheading}` but it is not working

Comment: My suggestion would be to edit your answer in such a way that it includes a minimal example containing what you've tried with `titlesec`. Please do not include the whole template in there, *only* the `\section` customization with `titlesec`, plus the things that are *required* in a valid document (`\documentclass`, ..., `\end{document}`).

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: That's better, but there is no *complete* minimal example as I said (see end of my previous comment).

Comment: The minimal complete working example is the full tex file itself isnt' it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this using `titlesec`'s `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing*` commands (I used `\titlespacing*` so that the paragraph following `\section` has no indentation; if you want it to have the usual `\parindent` indentation box, just use `\titlespacing` instead of `\titlespacing*`).

Note that I didn't look inside the replacement text of `\resheading`, except for removing the *before* and *after* vertical spaces that are better set with `\titlespacing` or `\titlespacing*`. Apart from these two spaces, this part of the code is *as provided in the question.* The same goes for the geometry settings, on which `\resheading` seems to have a very tight dependency.

The `explicit` option is passed to `titlesec` because we use `\resheading{#1}` in its fifth mandatory argument. Had we written only `\resheading` inside that argument, the same result would be obtained at the condition of removing the `explicit` option from the `\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}` line.

Your `Illegal parameter number` error is likely due to an invalid use of `#1` in one of the arguments of `\titleformat`, but since you didn't provide the minimal example I [asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503633/create-a-tex-section-in-cv-template-keeping-the-layout-of-a-custom-command/503649#comment1272166_503633) **containing your `titlesec` attempt**, it's impossible for me to tell with certainty. Maybe you used `#1` in an argument where it isn't allowed (such as the second mandatory argument), maybe you didn't pass the `explicit` option, maybe the problem was something else. I can reason on facts but have no crystal ball. Anyway, the following code works:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
% Width of border outside of title bars
\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}
% Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}
% Inner background color of title bars
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}

% You could use the geometry package for these things.
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}

\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}%
    \begin{shaded}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
    \end{shaded}%
  }%
}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{}{}{0pt}{\resheading{#1}}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{8pt}{5pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Education}
\lipsum[2]

\section{And now?}
\lipsum[3][1]

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]